# Do Background Tasks work with CloudKit in Swift?

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

I'm attempting to add a background task to my application and everything seems like it's working to register and schedule the task with the following code to register.

```
    static func registerTask() {
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: taskIdentifier, using: nil) { task in
            task.expirationHandler = {
                task.setTaskCompleted(success: false)
            }

            // Do things here 

            task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
        }
    }
```

and this to schedule:

```
    static func scheduleTask() {
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: taskIdentifier)
        request.earliestBeginDate = .now.addingTimeInterval(30)
        
            try? BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)        
    }
```

The issue is that after my schedule function runs and the app enters the background, I am getting the following type of errors:

---

*[BackgroundTask] Background Task 61 ("CoreData: CloudKit Import"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.*

*[tcp] tcp_output [C1.1.1.1:3] flags=[R.] seq=1263069135, ack=3409229275, win=2046 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=3409229275, snd_una=1263069058
2023-04-06 17:58:23.217898-0700 MyApp[14099:4978381] [error] error: Unexpected background task assertion cancellation.*

*[BackgroundTask] Background task still not ended after expiration handlers were called: <*UIBackgroundTaskInfo: 0x2805ac580>: taskID = 61, taskName = CoreData: CloudKit Import, creationTime = 508235 (elapsed = 76). This app will likely be terminated by the system. Call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(*:) to avoid this.*

---

I don't understand why this is happening because my background task has nothing to do with any of CoreData or CloudKit in the app, I use it to create a notification.

Triggering the task manually with Xcode flags is working correctly, but it seems like every time the background task is trying to fire on its own, it has some sort of issue with CloudKit.

This is also my only background task, and again, nothing to do with CoreData or Cloudkit.

Has anyone else run into something similar, or if you use CloudKit and background tasks, does it work all fine?

Thanks.

Comment: The error message mention `UIApplication.endBackgroundTask`. Do you have code that is using `UIApplication beginBackgroundTask`? That of course is different than the background request mechanism used in the code you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with your code.
The background task that is terminated is one of CoreData & CloudKit synchronization, in your case an import from iCloud that should be synced with the CoreData persistent store.
I have seen this type of error on a watch, which is of course much slower than an iPhone.
As long as your app is not really terminated, you should forget this warning. If it is terminated, I dare to suggest to write a bug report (mine have nearly never been processed or answered…).